# Oracle appending string to a select statement

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a column in a oracle table Lic_num char(7 byte)

```
SELECT column1, 'ABC' + Lic_num
FROM TABLE One
```

I wanted ABC appended to all the rows that are returned with lic_num
appended to it.

I tried tha above query and it is  not working.

Comment: "not working" is a very poor description of what happens. Are you getting an error message (what error message), does it crash, does it run but return the wrong result... Please be more specific.

Comment: This is pretty basic SQL, I don't want to be nasty but surely a quick google of "Oracle SQL concatenation operator" would have given you the answer you needed far faster than posting a question on here?

Comment: maybe but now it is faster for everyone else to check here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Oracle it's:

```
SELECT column1, 'ABC' || Lic_num
FROM TABLE_ONE
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way of doing it.

```
SELECT column1, 'ABC' || Lic_num FROM TABLE_ONE;
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(column1, 'ABC'), Lic_num) FROM TABLE_ONE;
```

If you need you can rename the concatenated Column name using `AS` keyword so it would be meaningful in terms of reporting.

Below info is included to help someone looking at concatenation in detail.

There are two ways to concatenate Strings in `Oracle SQL`. Either using `CONCAT` function or `||` operator.

`CONCAT` function allows you to concatenate two strings together

```
SELECT CONCAT( string1, string2 ) FROM dual;
```

Since `CONCAT` function will only **allow you to concatenate two values together**. If you want to concatenate more values than two, you can n**est multiple CONCAT function** calls.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('A', 'B'),'C') FROM dual;
```

An alternative to using the `CONCAT` function would be to use the **||** operator

```
SELECT 'My Name' || 'My Age' FROM dual;
```